# Response class with many observable collections 'does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#

I have a response class for static references, in the class it contains many collections - my issue is I want to only return collections where count > 0 but I get a `GetEnumerator` issue. I've looked around at different ways to implement `IEnumerable` but still having no success.

```
public class ReferencesResponse : BaseResponse, IEnumerable
{
    public ReferencesResponse(bool success, string errorMessage)
    {
        Success = success;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        Init();
    }

    public ReferencesResponse()
    {
        Success = true;
        Init();
    }
    
    internal void Init()
    {
        AuditTypes = new ObservableCollection<Reference>();
        NoteTypes= new ObservableCollection<Reference>();

    }


    public ObservableCollection<Reference> AuditTypes { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Reference> NoteTypes{ get; set; }
```

This is the reference response class that is used to return all the collections.
Once I have checked the database and passed the information back I get the response and all the collections inside but I cannot access the 'Count' to only return certain ones.

Any help would be appreciated or some helpers.

```
foreach (DataRow row in getReferences.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        string col = row.Table.Columns[0].ColumnName;

        ObservableCollection<Reference> values =
                                response.GetType().GetProperty(string.Concat(col, "s")).GetValue(response) as ObservableCollection<Reference>;
        values.Add(ModelHelper.Reference(row, col));
    }
    catch
    {
        // Silent catch if reference type property has not been found
    }
}
```

Comment: what is it you want to do when someone calls `foreach`? do you want it to behave as though they had called `foreach` on `.AuditTypes` ? or...? note: it looks like you're actually re-declaring the `AuditTypes` property, which is almost certainly not a good thing to do; "i want to only return collections where count > 0" - what does that mean? you have either 1 or maybe 2 collections (given the re-declare); are you enumerating the collections themselves? or the contents? or...? Side note: you should always prefer `IEnumerable<T>` over `IEnumerable`

Comment: I want to use Linq in order to return just the collections where the count > 0, so on the ReferenceResponse i think Similar to ReferenceResponse.Where(r => r.count > 0) - not sure if this is possible. I will be adding more collections to this list so will want to look at all of them within the response class

Comment: what "collections"? I see `AuditTypes`, duplicated (almost-certainly incorrectly), so: that's one collection. What "collections"?

Comment: can you edit it to correctly represent the issue? but: that means *one* collection - so again: what "collections"?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to enumerate the *collections* (not the contents of those collections), in which case you could do something like

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
   IList tmp = AuditTypes;
   if (tmp != null && tmp.Count != 0) yield return tmp;
   tmp = NoteTypes;
   if (tmp != null && tmp.Count != 0) yield return tmp;
   // ...
}
```

If you meant to enumerate the *contents* of the lists as a concatenated chunk, then I guess:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
   IList tmp = AuditTypes;
   if (tmp != null && tmp.Count != 0) foreach(var item in tmp) yield return item;
   tmp = NoteTypes;
   if (tmp != null && tmp.Count != 0) foreach(var item in tmp) yield return item;
   // ...
}
```

Note, however, that it is very unusual to just implement `IEnumerable`. Usually you want to implement `IEnumerable<T>` for some meaningful `T`, so the consumer knows what to expect.

Comment: Sorry - I think i've made this all very confusing (my first question) :). I want the class to always return all the collections, from a ReferenceController i have, that's where i want to return collections by looking at the count. Basically, i am getting a list of references back from the database via a stored procedure and build the reference response class, after this, any that have a count of 0 need to not be returned. again, sorry

Comment: @AB1 you're talking about a lot of things there that *aren't in the question*, so it is really hard to understand what you're trying to do and thus advise on a solution; "after this, any that have a count of 0 need to not be returned." - returned when? to whom? how? does the `GetEnumerator()` shown above not already do this?

Comment: I have a ReferenceController that will call the database and return the references, i then build the ReferenceResponse. I have added code to my question, the line at the bottom is the one where i get the error - (return response.where(r =>r.Count >0) where 'r' is the collection (i.e. AuditTypes) so when i return the response back it will only ever show the ReferenceResponse class with collections that are > 0, if that makes sense??

Comment: @A12 so, yeah, the `GetEnumerator()` shown above *does that*; I'd probably change it to be `IEnumerable<ObservableCollection<Reference>>`, but other than that ... it looks to do exactly what you've asked